# Can i get full number of attacks with a thrown returning weapon

Tags: pathfinder-1e, magic-items, ranged-attack

Is it possible to get full attack's worth of attacks when throwing a weapon with returning magical ability? If not, are there ways to get returning to each of thrown weapons without investing lots of money to multiple copies of returning thrown weapons?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

A *returning* weapon will

> Return to the wielders hand at the start of their next turn

This means that you only get one attack with one such weapon, regardless of your BAB.
If you want to throw the same weapon multiple times, look at the *blinkback belt*. That item

> Returns the weapon to the wielder after the attack is resolved

Which means, during the same turn, allowing it to be thrown again.

Now; this takes your belt slot, so you will give up your belt of dexterity (unless your GM allows you to combine items), so that is something to keep in mind

Comment: One's DM might allow the use of a Blinkback _glove_, amulet, magic trinket,  or something of the sort - sometimes at an additional gold cost, sometimes at no extra cost at all. Talk to your DM, they might have a solution for you. (Maybe even allowing to put _Blinkback_ on the weapon itself.)

Comment: Another solution you might want to mention is [Ricochet Toss](https://www.aonprd.com/FeatDisplay.aspx?ItemName=Ricochet%20Toss).